# Boot up issues after trying dual booting Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 7

Tags: boot

I tried dual booting Ubuntu 16.04 on my 32 bit pc alongside Windows 7. I tried the "Something else" option in one of the steps. However after successfully creating the required partitions Ubuntu started installing which was followed by some error(it probably might not have got installed as the "Install Ubuntu 16.04" icon was still displayed on the screen which did not open when I tried opening it). Now I had no other option rather than hitting the restart button on my CPU. But thereafter nothing shows up on the screen whenever I try to start my pc (not even bootloader). I literally mean nothing else than the brand name of my monitor.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You installed Ubuntu 16.04 64bit on a 32 bit system along side Windows?

Comment: Having the exact wording or screenshot of the error would help. You can, I guess, reproduce it by following all the described steps again.

Comment: @George :I downloaded the i386 iso file which is I guess for a 32 bit pc

Comment: @Hi-Angel :I can't as nothing shows up on the screen besides the brand name of monitor

Comment: @Useruw7 did bios stopped working too?

Comment: @Hi-Angel : Yes

Comment: Well, if BIOS indeed doesn't show up too, then what probably happened, is that for Ubuntu installation some kind of hardware failure occurred, resulting in the error you saw. There's nothing to do with Ubuntu or Windows, just a coincidence and bad luck. I'd recommend checking all cable connections in hope it's something simple. Otherwise you have to troubleshoot what hw broke.

Comment: @Hi-Angel :I have checked all connections and everything seems fine. Is there any other way or solution to this problem?

Comment: You can't have a software solution to a hardware problem leading to PC not loading even BIOS.

Comment: Since you asked though, I guess it's worth mentioning at least what to look at. It is for sure not peripheral devices like keyboard, mouse, and neither it's boot devices like DVD-reader, or HDD. Most probably, it's either of: CPU, GPU, motherboard, RAM. I can't help narrowing it even further, because I don't have enough hw-related experience to say what those faulty components could look like. That said, I still recommend before anything else to try to see BIOS for all peripheral and boot devices disconnected — just for the safe case, I recall seeing odd BIOS behavior regarding HDD.

Comment: @Hi-Angel So can you please tell me what can I do now more precisely in simple words.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I am extremely sorry to annoy you with this. But also thank you for all your help till now and further.

Comment: You have to disassemble PC, disconnect HDD(s) and DVD-rom(s), connect a monitor, and turn it on to check if you'll see the BIOS logo. Be careful to not touch power lines with anything. If it didn't work, and you still only see the monitor logo, it gets difficult — offhand I don't have advises, you'd either have google it up, or to ask someone more acknowledged. By the way, you know, accidental thought: is it possible that BIOS logo simply flashes behind the monitor one? Try pressing F *[1..12]* keys on start, maybe you'll see settings appearing.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: @Hi-Angel My PC  finally somehow started working fine. Thanks for your help